# Can we solve this system of inequalities analytically?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

Let $A$ be positive real number and $k$ a positive integer.

How to find the analytical solution of this system? Find the $a_i$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\left(1+a_i\right)\geq k\ln\left(1+A/k\right),\\ 
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na_i\leq A,\\
\displaystyle a_i>0\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}